# What items does Krinjh carry when he first joins the party?

Tags: final-fantasy-the-4-heroes-of-light

What are the items (weapons, armor, magic tomes, et cetera) that Krinjh carries when he first joins the party?

Is there anything (lower character levels) that affects this?  I restarted my game, but I could have sworn that the first time, he carried a second spellbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krinjh carries a Krinjh's Sword, a Wood Shield, a Krinjh's Robe and an Areo tome.  There is no variation in this.

http://rpgcodex.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=1422668#1422668